# Xamarin.IOS push notifications don't work

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

I try to register app in apns but I get error:

`error    {no valid “aps-environment” entitlement string found for application}`

at

`public void FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSError error)`

My provisional profile is ok(development the same):
[image: screenshot]

I tried to add to Entitlements.plist "aps-environment" + "production""development" but I didn't work

I use visual studio for Mac, debug at iPhone 12 mini

Comment: Have you generated Development or Production SSL Certificate for App Id?

Comment: https://radikal.host/i/c2cPIA
This is my certificates list

Comment: Please confirm that you have enabled the Push Notification feature in Entitlement.plist. And make sure you have add the Entitlement.plist file in both Debug and Release mode in Bundle Signing.